# Mysterious Vertical Space After Theorem/Proof Environments

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I have defined my own theorem style to have 0pt above and 0pt below. For simplicity I have also set all other relevant spacings to 0pt. However, when I use a theorem or proof environment I get some mysterious white space below.

Note that I don't get any space above (so the `0pt` above in `\newtheoremstyle` seems to be working). Can anyone tell me where the space is coming from? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bf}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.
\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}
Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above. \par
The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `proof` environment resets `\topsep`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `proof` environment resets `\topsep` before opening a `trivlist`; you can remove this setting by redefining `\proof` or by patching it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,xpatch}

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.
\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}
Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above. \par
The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope this is just for studying how LaTeX works, because the output is terrible.

Please, note that `\bf` has been obsolete for twenty years and `\bfseries` should be used.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm surprised I couldn't find the answer on the internet already; sorry. And yes, I am new to LaTeX - I've been adapting a template sent to me from my supervisor which probably explains the obsolete command. 

Out of interest, what else is terrible about the output? It's only a test file and obviously the spacing is dodgy.

Comment: @TomOffer Spaces added before and after theorem and proofs are for the reader, who can better identify them when skimming through the pages.

Comment: Yes, I know that! As I said, I set all the spacings to 0pt above so my problem could easily be seen. The patch works in my test file but not in my actual document... is there an obvious reason why that might be?

Comment: It seems that I get a `\parskip` and a `\topsep` before and after the proof environment. How can I patch it to ignore one of them?

Comment: @TomOffer `\parskip` is *always* inserted by TeX as soon as a paragraph starts. The `trivlist` used by `proof` inserts `\topsep` before and after it.

Comment: So it seems that I need to just remove the `\topsep` from the `trivlist` (then the only spacing before and after `\proof` will be `\parskip`). How do I do that?

Comment: @TomOffer Several parts of LaTeX are based on `trivlist` and I'd not recommend changing it. I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to achieve; as I said, removing spaces around statements and proofs is not a good service to your readers.