# Mysterious Vertical Space After Theorem Environment Before Align Environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, theorems, amsthm

There are a lot of questions about skip control before and after theorem and align environments, see, please, [solution with hack of theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68413/44348), [general solution for align environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47403/44348), however unexpected mysterious skip has come back.

As a MWE we can use a mixture of MWEs given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232659/44348) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237762/44348).

It happens that only white `\hrule` can slightly improve the situation, however this solution is a little bit ugly.

The question is how not to get unexpected skip in a simple and reasonable way?

Here is a MWE:

`MisteriousSkip.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,xpatch}

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.
\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\end{lemma}
%\hrule % if we \hrule, the skip becomes smaller!
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &\leq 10 \\
x_5+x_5         &\leq 8 \\
x_7+x_8         &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}
Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above. \par
The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

A screenshot of MysteriousSkip.pdf is below:

[image]

Comment: So, why do not include the `align*` as part of your `lemma`?

Comment: Well, the equation forms part of the `lemma`, doesn't it? So, keep it that way, otherwise it's just an equation between a `lemma` and a `proof`, breaking up the two. No one wants to be broken up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `align` is part of the proof, include it within that environment. Also, it would be advisable to *not* start a proof with an equation, particularly because of the setup - it sets `Proof.` by default, necessarily putting the alignment on the following line. Instead, add some informal descriptive text prior to it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.

\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
It is possible to derive the following:
\begin{align*}
  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4                        &\leq 10 \\
                         x_5 + x_6             &\leq 8 \\
                                    x_7 + x_8  &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}

Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above.

The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Werner, thank you for the answer, however actually I need to add some conditions inside a `lemma` or theorem-like environment. In this case extra skip appears! A white `\hrule` or `\vspace*{0pt}` can be useful, however a little bit expensive decision. Everywhere I need to put one of these commands.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: Please provide a *complete*, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem so it can be replicated.

Comment: @ Werner, the example is complete, we should drop an extra skip between a lemma and align environments. Your way with embedded environments is working very good with `proof`, however it  does not work if we put `align` inside a `lemma`.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: I get a zero skip between the text in the lemma and the start of `align`. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXriQ.png); [code](http://pastebin.com/j697LmQg)

Comment: Dear @Werner, thank you for the last link, finally I fixed a bug - there was an empty line before `align` in the embedded decision.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a skip. as always in TeX if you can not start a paragraph with display math, if you try, a spurious white paragraph just consisting of indentation  and parfillskip is generated. Not only does this look like extra vertical space, being a paragraph line not vertical space, it is not dropped if the page break happens at that point.

You can see this if you add some text

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,xpatch}

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.
\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\end{lemma}
%\hrule % if we \hrule, the skip becomes smaller!
xxx
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &\leq 10 \\
x_5+x_5         &\leq 8 \\
x_7+x_8         &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}
Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above. \par
The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The display does not move, but the one line paragraph above it now has visible text.

Solutions are to write something meaningful instead of `xxx` or to move the `align` inside the lemma

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,xpatch}

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{0pt}{0pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{} 

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
Some normal text goes here, with a lemma immediately below.
\begin{lemma}
This is the statement of the lemma.
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &\leq 10 \\
x_5+x_5         &\leq 8 \\
x_7+x_8         &\leq 5 
\end{align*}
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma, with a mysterious space above.
\end{proof}
Some normal text goes here, with a mysterious space above. \par
The next paragraph comes immediately below.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ David, thank you for the explanations, the problem turned to be inlined in `Tex` logic. I accepted Werner's answer as the first solution.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko that's OK Werner needs the points to catch me up anyway:-)